# InputStream Java

Tags: java, eclipse, input, archivo

Hola tengo un problema cunado leo un archivo, me tira error en el while en la Ioexeption nose que estoy haciendo mal.
Tengo diferentes tipos de objetos cargados, y cuando realizo la peticion para imprimir los objetos me trae uno y después me trae el error. solamente da una vuelta en el while

```
public void leerCombo()
{
    FileInputStream file = null;
    Combo combo = null;
    
    try {
        
        file = new FileInputStream("combos.bin");
        ObjectInputStream object = new ObjectInputStream(file);
        while((combo = (Combo) object.readObject()) != null) 
        {
                System.out.println(combo.toString());   
        }
        
        object.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public void agregarCombo(Combo combo) 
{
    FileOutputStream file = null;
    try 
    {
        file = new FileOutputStream("combos.bin");
        ObjectOutputStream object = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
        
        object.writeObject(combo);
        object.close();
        
    }catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            file.close();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Y el error que recibo es:

```
java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
    at Archivos.ArchivoProducto.leerCombo(ArchivoProducto.java:55)
    at paquete.Main.main(Main.java:78)
```

Comment: Los objetos combo contenidos en el fichero "combos.bin" podrian tener atributos o tipos distintos al de la clase que usas ahora como modelo para "de-seralizar". ¿Es posible que hayas modificado la clase Combo despues de serializar los objetos?

Comment: at Archivos.ArchivoProducto.leerCombo(ArchivoProducto.java:59)
 at paquete.Main.main(Main.java:78)
Combo Combo Salsas
 Precio = $230
 Productos --> [Gaseosa 237cc Linea Pepsi Precio : $60, Pancho [esVeggie=false, cantToppings=0], Papas Fritas]
 Observaciones:

Comment: El tema es que me muestra uno, y despues me lanza el error, no cambie los objetos solo los guarde y ahora queria mostarlos, si quito el while no me tira error

Comment: ¿Qué tienes guardado en el archivo combos.bin? ¿Cómo lo has generado?

Comment: public void agregarCombo(Combo combo) 
 {
  FileOutputStream file = null;
  try 
  {
   file = new FileOutputStream("combos.bin");
   ObjectOutputStream object = new ObjectOutputStream(file);
   
   object.writeObject(combo);
   object.close();
   
  }catch(IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }finally {
   try {
    file.close();
   }catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }

Comment: usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda la infor en la pregunta.. en los comentarios no se entiende nada

Comment: y el error es que estas leyendo, pero llegaste al fin del archivo y no estas verificando eso

Comment: el while != null no lo verifica?

Answer (score 1):

El método [readObject](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#readObject()) no retorna `null` cuando llega al final del archivo, sino, lanza la excepción [EOFException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/EOFException.html). Por lo tanto, debes capturar dicha excepción con el `try-catch`.

**Ejemplo:**

```java
public void leerCombo()
{
        FileInputStream file = null;
        ObjectInputStream object = null;
        Combo combo = null;

        try 
        {

            file = new FileInputStream("combos.bin");
            object = new ObjectInputStream(file);
            while(true) 
            {
                combo = (Combo) object.readObject();
                System.out.println(combo.toString());
                //El bucle se romperá cuando se llegue al final del archivo
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(EOFException e)
        {
            //Este catch se ejecutará cuando se llegue al final del archivo
            System.out.println("Llegamos al final del archivo!");
        }
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                if(object.close() != null)
                    object.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Como verás, los recursos no se cierran adentro del `try`, sino, en el bloque `finally`.

Para no tener que estar cerrando los recursos manualmente, puedes usar los [bloques try-witch-resources](https://picodotdev.github.io/blog-bitix/2018/04/la-sentencia-try-with-resources-de-java/):

```java
void leerCombo()
{
        Combo combo = null;

        try(FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("combos.bin");
            ObjectInputStream object = new ObjectInputStream(file))
        {
            while(true) 
            {
                combo = (Combo) object.readObject();
                System.out.println(combo.toString());
                //El bucle se romperá cuando se llegue al final del archivo
            }
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(EOFException e)
        {
            //Este catch se ejecutará cuando se llegue al final del archivo
            System.out.println("Llegamos al final del archivo!");
        }
        catch(IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } 
}
```